# Login with Facebook and fetch email and user info for iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am newbie in iOS and I am working on app in which I need to integrate facebook with my App just for login purpose and to fetch user info on login user. I just read few tutorial but those are for sharing purpose, which I don't need those. I also want that if user login from facebook that should be  save in settings (my client requirement)? Kindly suggest me few links. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can implement it with Facebook SDK.**

There are two ways to implement Facebook login in your iOS app: using the Facebook login button or implementing your custom login UI using API calls.

This is how you request for permissions for information to want to read.

```
FBLoginView *loginView = 
    [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:
        @[@"public_profile", @"email"]];
```

When you implement FBLoginViewDelegate

```
// This method will be called when the user information has been fetched
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
  self.profilePictureView.profileID = user.id;
  self.nameLabel.text = user.name;
}
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0

Above link has all you need with sample/example code.

**If you don't want to use Facebook SDK. Same thing can be achieved using Social Framework.**

```
SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                     requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                               URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"]
                                        parameters:nil];
request.account = _account; // This is the _account from your code
[request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil && ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response).statusCode == 200) {
        NSError *deserializationError;
        NSDictionary *userData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&deserializationError];

        if (userData != nil && deserializationError == nil) {
            NSString *email = userData[@"email"];
            NSLog(@"%@", email);
        }
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks Balpreet, can this account will also be save in setting facebook option?

Comment: @Josh: Facebook sdk may persist session information. But other info like user's name, email etc. you will need to manage/store at your end in your app.

Comment: yes you right this persist session in app where its integrated, or in facebook app (If we use SSO) but I think this info will not be save in settings. I am more concern about this because I have to integrate this with iOS 7 not before than that. So any idea how can I achieve my target?

Comment: 1) When you say "setting" which exact settings you are referring to? 
2) And what info exactly you want to persist? 
3) Are you concerned that you will not be able to support iOS 6?

Comment: 1. Like go in settings(app) and on botton you'll see facebook and twitter.
2. Email, first name, last name that it.
3. No I am sure that this app is not for ios 6 or below os versions.
This is all my client requirement, that it should be save in settings after login after fetching info.

Comment: When you ask for login/profile info etc. User will be asked to give permissions to your app. Once user give permission, your app will automatically appear in settings app under facebook option.

Comment: Thanks Balpreet, this will be cool if this work as it is as you are saying, just need bit more help. Is this function you are saying"loginViewFetchedUserInfo"?
And Any helping code or demo project available for this task?
Thanks Again looking for your response?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55837/discussion-between-balpreet-patil-and-josh).

Answer (score 0):

In YourClass.h file.

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@interface YourClass : UIViewController<FBLoginViewDelegate>

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet FBLoginView *loginFacebook;
```

In YourClass.m file.

```
@synthesize loginFacebook;
```

In ViewDidLoad

```
-(Void)ViewDidLoad
{

    loginFacebook =
        [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email",@"user_friends",nil] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends];

        for (id obj in loginFacebook.subviews)
        {
            if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            {
                UIButton * loginButton =  obj;

                UIImage *loginImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook-off.png"];
                [loginButton setBackgroundImage:loginImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
                [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
                //[loginButton sizeToFit];
            }
            if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
            {
                UILabel * loginLabel =  obj;
                loginLabel.text =@""; //@"Log in to facebook";
                loginLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                loginLabel.frame =CGRectMake(123,149, 280, 55);// CGRectMake(0, 0, 271, 37);
            }
        }

        loginFacebook.delegate = self;

        if (IsIphone5)
        {
            loginFacebook.frame =CGRectMake(29, 249, 263, 54);
        }
        else
        {
            loginFacebook.frame =CGRectMake(29, 240, 263, 54);
        }

        [self.view addSubview:loginFacebook];

      [Super ViewDidLoad];
 }
```

## pragma mark Facebook

```
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
{

}
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{    
    Nslog(@"=== %@",User);
}
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
{

    NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    FBSession* session = [FBSession activeSession];
    [session closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    //        [FBSession setActiveSession:nil];
    for (NSHTTPCookie *each in cookieStorage.cookies)
    {
        [cookieStorage deleteCookie:each];
    }
}
- (void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView
      handleError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"== %@",error.localizedDescription);
}
```